# MIPS Simulator --- read instructions into memory (C++)

Tags: c++, mips, simulator, 32-bit

I need to read a 32 bit address in hex format (ex: 0129ef12) and split up the 32 bits into 6-5-5-16 packets that represent Opcode-Rd-Rs-Immediate, respectively.

This is what I have so far:

```
typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned short u16;

union {
   unsigned int address;
   struct {
       u16 imm : 16;
       u8 rs : 5;
       u8 rd : 5;
       u8 opcode : 6;
   } i;
} InstRead;

InstRead.address = 0x0129ef12;

cout << hex << int(InstRead.i.opcode) << "\n";
cout << hex << int(InstRead.i.rs) << "\n";
cout << hex << int(InstRead.i.rd) << "\n";
cout << hex << int(InstRead.i.imm) << "\n";
```

However, this does not give the correct output... i.e the bits are not selected by the lengths 6-5-5-16 that I have specified... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What output do you get? Have you tried step-through debugging? Are the values of the `i` members correct?

Comment: What compiler are you using? bit field handling is not standardized and is left up to the compiler to implement. It could be that it's padding those bit fields you specified to a nearest boundary. In fact, I would be surprised if it wasn't.

Comment: Couldn't endianness be an issue here ?

Answer (score 1):

```
union {
   unsigned int address;
   unsigned int imm : 16,
       rs : 5,
       rd : 5,
       opcode : 6;

} InstRead;
```

See if you have better luck with that union. It will depend on your compiler though.

Comment: Thanks for your help Aumnayan! But this output still gives me

opcode: 12
rs: 12
rd: 12
imm: ef12

Comment: I guess it would be better for me to try a different method altogether.. Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume you expect 0x0129 out of imm, which is what I would expect given the numbers and definition. This implies an endian problem as Alexandre C. stated above. You can try endian converting the address prior to utilizing the bitfields.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me (gcc 4.8.3 on Windows 7).

You can use bit operations to extract the fields in a more portable manner:

```
imm = address & 0xffff;
rs  = address & 0x1f0000 >> 16; 
// et cetera
```